# Clueless on how to execute big tasks on C++ AMP

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, gpu, gpgpu, c++-amp

I have a task to see if an algorithm I developed can be ran faster using computing on GPU rather than CPU. I'm new to computing on accelerators, I was given a book "C++ AMP" which I've read thoroughly, and I thought I understood it reasonably well (I coded in C and C++ in the past but nowadays its mostly C#).

However, when going into real application, I seem to just not get it. So please, help me if you can.

Let's say I have a task to compute some complicated function that takes a huge matrix input (like 50000 x 50000) and some other data and outputs matrix of same size. Total calculation for the whole matrix takes several hours.

On CPU, I'd just cut tasks into several pieces (number of pieces being something like 100 or so) and execute them using Parralel.For or just a simple task managing loop I wrote myself. Basically, keep several threads running (num of threads = num of cores), start new part when thread finishes, until all parts are done. And it worked well!

However, on GPU, I cannot use the same approach, not only because of memory constraints (that's ok, can partition into several parts) but because of the fact that if something runs for over 2 seconds it's considered a "timeout" and GPU gets reset! So, I must ensure that every part of my calculation takes less than 2 seconds to run.

But that's not every task (like, partition a hour-long work into 60 tasks of 1sec each), which would be easy enough, thats every bunch of tasks, because no matter what queue mode I choose (immediate or automatic), if I run (via parralel_for_each) anything that takes in total more than 2s to execute, GPU will get reset.

Not only that, but if my CPU program hogs all CPU resource, as long as it is kept in lower priority, UI stays interactive - system is responsive, however, when executing code on GPU, it seems that screen is frozen until execution is finished!

So, what do I do? In the demonstrations to the book (N-Body problem), it shows that it is supposed to be like 100x as effective (multicore calculations give 2 gflops, or w/e amount of flops that was, while amp give 200 gflops), but in real application, I just don't see how to do it!

Do I have to partition my big task into like, into billions of pieces, like, partition into pieces that each take 10ms to execute and run 100 of them in parralel_for_each at a time?

Or am I just doing it wrong, and there is a better solution I just don't get?

Help please!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602312/gpu-card-resets-after-2-seconds

Comment: No, this is unfortunately not what I'm looking for, I don't need to increase the timeout, because that would make user display freeze for the whole operation, which is obviously undesireable.

Comment: Surely display freezing is a separate issue, you should always be executing long-running tasks on a thread separate to the GUI thread so the UI can stay responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TDRs (the 2s timeouts you see) are a reality of using a resource that is shared between rendering the display and executing your compute work. The OS protects your application from completely locking up the display by enforcing a timeout. This will also impact applications which try and render to the screen. Moving your AMP code to a separate CPU thread will not help, this will free up your UI thread on the CPU but rendering will still be blocked on the GPU.

You can actually see this behavior in the n-body example when you set N to be very large on a low power system. The maximum value of N is actually limited in the application to prevent you running into these types of issues in typical scenarios.

You are actually on the right track. You do indeed need to break up your work into chunks that fit into sub 2s chunks or smaller ones if you want to hit a particular frame rate. You should also consider how your work is being queued. Remember that all AMP work is queued and in automatic mode you have no control over when it runs. Using immediate mode is the way to have better control over how commands are batched.

Note: TDRs are not an issue on dedicated compute GPU hardware (like Tesla) and Windows 8 offers more flexibility when dealing with TDR timeout limits if the underlying GPU supports it.